# Piling Objects Animation

Tags: python, animation-nodes, mathematics, geometry-nodes

I've seen a lot of motion graphics animations from Cinema4D, I recently saw [this effect on Youtube with a script on Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8MUFXfxpek).

I was wondering if it is possible to get this effect with animation nodes.

This is the basis of my file :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest way would be something like this:

(Animation Nodes version)
[image]

(Geometry nodes version)
[image]

[image]

Comment: great!!!!!!!! +1